# Split string with specified separator without omitting empty elements

Tags: java, string, split

Right now I am using

```
StringUtils.split(String str, char separatorChar)
```

to split input string with specified separator (`,`).

Example input data:

```
a,f,h
```

Output

```
String[] { "a", "f", "h" }
```

But with following input:

```
a,,h
```

It returns just

```
String[] { "a", "h" }
```

What I need is just empty string object:

```
String[] { "a", "", "h" }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the [String.split(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method, no need for StringUtils:

```
"a,,h".split(","); // gives ["a", "", "h"]
```

Comment: Note that `String.split` will still omit empty strings from the end of the array, e.g., `"a,h,".split(",")` gives `["a","h"]`, not `["a","h",""]`.  To get the empty strings from the end, you can supply a negative number as the second argument to split. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) Sometimes Java is weird...

Answer (score 12):

If you are going to use `StringUtils`  then call the `splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens()` method instead of `split()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use this overloaded split()

```
public String[] split(String regex,
                  int limit)
```

The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter

For more visit [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 3):

The ordinary [`String.split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) does what you're after.

`"a,,h".split(",")`  yields  `{ "a", "", "h" }`.

### [ideone.com demonstration](http://ideone.com/Nq0Bm).

Answer (score 1):

Split string with specified separator without omitting empty elements.

Use the method `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens()`

Advantage over other method's of different class :

- It does not skip any sub-string or empty string and works fine for all char's or string as delimiter.
- It also has a polymorphic form where we can specify the max number of tokens expected from a given string.

`String.Split()` method take's regex as parameter, So it would work for some character's as delimiter but not all **eg:** pipe(|),etc. We have to append escape char to pipe(|) so that it should work fine.

`Tokenizer`(String or stream) - it skips the empty string between the `delimiter's`.